# Single Sign On (SSO) Scenario - Please Provide Guidance

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, wif, saml

I have a centralized credentials store that is used for several websites / web-portals.

Each website has its own unique domain and branding specific to one customer.

I want to display a login form on each portal and validate those credentials against the centralized credential store.  In addition, I would like to enforce a variety of password policies.  For example, a user's password may expire after a certain number of days.  Or there may be a requirement to have 8 characters with 1 letter + 1 digit + 1 special character.

I would be OK with redirecting users to a centralized website for the majority of this password maintenance, however I really want to allow for users to enter a username / password on the custom domain for their portal.

I am familiar with SAML and it seems to *almost* get me there.  However, it does not seem to support collecting credentials on the Service Provider.

I would prefer not to come up with an Ad-Hoc solution, but would rather use a standardized solution like SAML that has been rigorously designed by a committee.

I am willing to consider a WIF based solution as well.

Comment: This statement "I would be OK with redirecting users to a centralized website for the majority of this password maintenance, however I really want to allow for users to enter a username / password on the custom domain for their portal." is really confusing for me.

Comment: Do you want: _a) One cred store for several sites, users must register on each site separately_ or _b) A user can register on one site and then use the same login/password on the other sites_ or _c) Same as b) but with the additional requirement that a user that is logged in on site FOO should automatically be recognized when coming to site BAR_?

Comment: @SureshAtt - In many Identity Provider situations, users are redirected to the Identity Provider's for all profile maintenance (login, changing password, etc).  Stackoverflow for example redirects you to Google/Yahoo/etc in order for login.  Using the Stackoverflow example, my preference would be allow users to enter their Google username/password on stackoverflow.com for login purposes.

Comment: @user1429080 - Users must login to each site separately.  In fact, if the same username is used on multiple sites, no data will be shared between accounts.  Behind the scenes the Users table has a unique key of (SiteId, UserName).  This is actually in place today. The issue is that if I want to add functionality (say redirecting users to a "change password" page when their password is expired) I must update each website's code.  There are currently about 20 of these sites, but the number is growing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your credential store is not AD?

Best plan is to use a custom STS. If you are using SQL Server, have a look at [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/). This doesn't support SAML but you can federate it to ADFS which does.

Each application would then use WIF.

On your custom STS, place all the self-service password stuff on your login page.

So everyone will share the same login page on the STS.

If you want the login page on each site, then you can use WIF active profile and connect to the STS login via a web service. But then you have to have the self-service stuff on many pages which is going to complicate maintenance.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  My credentials store uses SQL Server.  It already exists and is in use today.  I might be interested in connecting to the STS using a web-service.  Is there a "standardized" way to do this?  I am looking into using WIF.  I have heard a lot about it, but never implemented anything with it.  It seems kind of strange I have to build my own STS, but it seems like WIF solves the "Relying Party" issue and most of the samples seem to connect to ADFS.

Comment: Are all your websites ASP.NET? If so, just hook then up directly using WIF to IdentityServer. WIF uses WS-Federation which IdentityServer supports. IIRC, there are some web service examples in the Training Kit. Another way is to grab the credentials from the web site and then post them as query strings (hashed in some way) and then extract them on the STS side and plug them into the login text boxes.

Comment: OK, you've given me some good ideas to work with.  I still find it odd you have to setup my own STS, but I'll take a look at Identity Server and maybe some others.  Thank you.

Comment: ADFS ONLY authenticates again AD so you can't use it.